# Yarn does not work in WSL when I change the directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently downloaded WSL on my system as well as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I installed Node JS on it and it seems to work fine.
But when I tried installing yarn from the following command:

`curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`

It installed yarn 1.22.5 and when I ran `yarn --version`, it returned `1.22.5`

But when I changed the directory to `/mnt/c/Users/user-name` and tried running `yarn --version`, it threw this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/mnt/c/users/user-name/C:\Users\user-name\.yarn\releases\yarn-1.22.10.cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)      
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

**I found a solution to this:**

Check [this](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable) page out. Click on `Alternatives` and select the operating system `Debian / Ubuntu` and version `Classic Stable (1.22.5)`.

You can follow the given instructions to install yarn from the Debian package repository, then have a look at the `Path Setup` section. Follow the instructions given there and yarn will be available globally!

Then you can run `yarn --version` any where in you're *Ubuntu* shell and it should be working just fine!

Comment: At first glance, this appears to likely be a Windows path problem in WSL.  Do you have the Windows version of node installed with yarn also?  What does `which yarn` give you (in each directory -- the one where it works, and the one where it fails)?  Also, looking at your path may be helpful.

Comment: In the directory where yarn works, `which yarn` returns `/home/user-name/.yarn/bin/yarn` and in the directory where yarn doesn't work, `which yarn` returns `/home/user-name/.yarn/bin/yarn`. It returns the same in both the directories. Can you help me with the PATH in WSL.

Comment: (1) `echo $PATH` for starters.  By default, WSL appends the Windows path, so that you can easily access Windows executables.  However, sometimes this gets in the way.  Do you see anything unusual in there?  (2) Also confirm that there isn't a single "period" anywhere in the path.  (3) I should have also recommended `which node`.  If that still returns something in the Linux filesystem, then it's probably not the problem I was originally thinking.

Comment: I tried the `echo $PATH` command, and after observing the results, it doesn't seem to have any "period" in there. `which node` returns `/home/user-name/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node`. What are the options left with me to fix this?

Comment: Hey, I found a solution to this. Check [this](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable) page out. Click on `Alternatives` and select `Debian / Ubuntu`. The instructions given in the 'Path Setup' section seemed to work for me!

Comment: Excellent - Good to hear!  Please add that as a self-answer below.  Thanks!